# Sending HTML email templates using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, html-email, email-templates

I have created a file with name dummy.blade.php which has the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-EN">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#11C9FF">
   {{$emailBody}}
  </body>
 </html>
```

And I am trying to send HTML content using:

```
 Mail::send('emailTemplates.dummy', ['emailBody'=>'<h1>TESTING</h1>'], function($message)
 {
 $message->to($myEmail)->subject('Password reset');
 });
```

And the email received is like this:

[image]

As per documentation that I should be receiving the html format but I am receiving simple text based email. Any clues?

Comment: `Mail::send(['html' => 'view'], $data, $callback);` it is mentioned in laravel docs

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain so is this: By default, the view given to the send method is assumed to contain HTML. However, by passing an array as the first argument to the send method, you may specify a plain text view to send in addition to the HTML view:

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I should have mentioned that, I have already tried that..

Comment: try replacing `auto-escaped block {{{ }}}` with `unescaped {!! $emailBody !!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting the answer as that could be useful for others.
changed

```
  {{$emailBody}}
```

to

```
  <?= $emailBody ?>
```

and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Double curly braces escape the html inside them, you need to use different syntax for an unescaped string.

So instead of

```
{{ $emailBody }}
```

you should use

```
{!! $emailBody !!}
```

You can read more about here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

By default, the view given to the send method is assumed to contain HTML. However, by passing an array as the first argument to the send method, you may specify a plain text view to send in addition to the HTML view:

`Mail::send(['html.view', 'text.view'], $data, $callback);`

Or, if you only need to send a plain text e-mail, you may specify this using the text key in the array:

`Mail::send(['text' => 'view'], $data, $callback);`